# Swagger (using flask-restx/plus) optional list/nested JSON

Tags: flask-restplus, flask-restx

I need the API to accept:

```
{
  'field1' : 10,
  'children' : [ 'c1', 'c2' ]
}
```

and also

```
{
  'field1' : 10,
}
```

i.e., when there are *no* children the field can be skipped.

I tried defining the model:

```
  'field1'   : fields.Integer(example=42),
  'children' : fields.Nested(child_model, as_list=True, allow_null=True, required=False)
```

and also as:

```
  'field1'   : fields.Integer(example=42),
  'children' : fields.List(fields.Nested(child_model, as_list=True, allow_null=True), required=False)
```

and pretty much all combinations of `as_list`, `allow_null`, 'skip_none`and`default` (None, [], etc)

I expected `required=False` to work for `List` and/or `Nested` the same way it works other types.
If the server does not include `children` in the JSON, marshaling always adds some value .. however, when the client returns an identical JSON to the server marshaling complains.

How can I achieve *optional* list/nested JSON?